# Angular 2 : Date format

Tags: angular

I'm receiving from an external system, dates as string :
Format : DDMMYYYYhhmmss (exp : 14022018225400).

I want to convert them to DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss for the HTML5 display.

I tried DatePipe but it seem I must add '**T**' between date and time : 14022018**T**225400. Otherwise the conversion fails. How can I convert to DD/MM/YYYY hh:mm:ss without adding '**T**'.

{{ "01022018113025" | date:'hh:mm:ss' }}  => 11:55:13 (KO)

{{ "01022018**T**113025" | date:'hh:mm:ss' }} => 11:30:25 (OK)

Here's DatePipe doc :

https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Regard.

Comment: Instead of a perennially inaccurate resource like w3schools, you may want to instead refer to the [official documentation](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: Also your w3schools link is for AngularJS, not Angular.

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you use [`momentjs`](https://momentjs.com/) library when working with dates, it's a nice to have library I use in all my projects in frontend.

If you use `momentjs` then you can do something like this:

```
$date = moment("01022018113025", "DDMMYYYYhhmmss");
```

Then in your html you can do:

```
{{ $date | date:'hh:mm:ss' }} => 11:30:25 (OK)
```